# Can I render this kind of drop down using CSS?

Tags: css, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I want to buid a web page. The page contains a drop down which should look like this:

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/9350/dropdown.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/9350/dropdown.png)

Is it possible using CSS or I would need to use a image with some javascipt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make using this jquery plugin

http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Comment: This looks good...but what if I need to bind the dropdown from code behind.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to style a select box like this. You have to make a custom one using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible without Javascript as long as the dropdown is to open automatically when you move the mouse over the button. "[Son of suckerfish](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)" is a popular drop-down menu implementation with only minimal added Javascript for older browsers, I have never used it for a standalone button but it should be easy to achieve.

A click-sensitive dropdown can't, to my knowledge, be done using pure CSS.

> Edit: on second reading, I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Are you talking about the hand-drawn *look* of the button, or the *behaviour* of a dropdown button?

Comment: but i think he need to open drop down using click on arrow and sun of sucker fish works on mouse over

Comment: I think he's looking for a drop down list (<select>) implementation rather than a drop down menu.

Comment: @Jitendra: you could use `:focus` for newer browsers and `:active` pseudo-class for <IE8 assuming the "select" element is a link.

Comment: @Pekka: I did have added the UI tag to my question...!!

Comment: Unfortunately, javascript would be required to set the currently selected option.

Comment: @Manish: Since when is drop down functionality not part of the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a combination of CSS and javascript to create a custom select box.  Unfortunately,  elements aren't very stylable in most browsers.

**EDIT**

An example: http://lab.aspektas.com/select/select.html